# Where does Apple Store preflight files before rebooting for update

Tags: startup, sonoma

I was told Sonoma install was going to restart my system. I decided I wanted to shut the system down instead.
I then restarted into Recovery mode to restore my boot drive onto an another drive for backup.
When that was done I attempted to restart from the boot drive and could not.
I reset PRAM, SMC, restarted into Recovery again and checked the disk - was fine - then decide to reinstall Ventura. When I did that I was met with an error for the boot disk.
[image]

I am fairly sure that the Sonoma install files are interfering with boot. However, I am unsure how to stop them from attempting to install Sonoma on each restart. I have Terminal open in Restore but can’t locate the boot files for the Sonoma install.